# Массив всех возможных комбинаций из '0' и '1'

Tags: c#, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Нужно создать двумерный битовый (булевый) массив всех возможных комбинаций из `0` и `1` (`false` и `true`), размерность массива - параметр. Например, для входящего значения `3` результат должен быть

```
0   0   0,
0   0   1,
0   1   1,
1   0   0,
1   0   1,
1   1   1
```

Что-то завис.

Comment: Комбинаций - 8, а не 6 (пропущены 010 и 110). А какой ответ для [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]  и трех позиций?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7):

Если 010 и 110 пропущены случайно, то результат - это двоичные представления всех чисел от 0 до 2<sup>n</sup>-1:

```
int size = 3;
bool[][] result =
    Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << size)
    .Select(i => new BitArray(new int[] { i }).Cast<bool>().Take(size).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 7):

Если интересуют именно **все** возможные комбинации, и нет острой необходимости иметь результат в виде массива, то можно создать класс, реализующий индексное свойство:

```
public sealed class BitArray2D
{
    private readonly int highestBitIndex;

    public BitArray2D(int bitsCount)
    {
        highestBitIndex = bitsCount - 1;
    }

    public bool this[int rowIndex, int colIndex]
    {
        get
        {
            return (rowIndex & (1 << (highestBitIndex - colIndex))) != 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Этот класс позволит не выделять лишнюю память, а будет просто быстро вычислять значения при обращении.

Пример:

```
var t = new BitArray2D(3);
Console.WriteLine(t[3, 0]);  // False
Console.WriteLine(t[3, 1]);  // True
Console.WriteLine(t[3, 2]);  // True
```

Comment: А где сами комбинации? И зачем `//False` и `//True`?

Comment: @MiKeBu Комбинация - это двоичное представление числа `rowIndex`, переданного в индексное свойство. Далее в этом числе просто проверяется бит `colIndex`. `// True` и `// False` - это так показана выдача соответствующего оператора в консоль.

Comment: а как с помощью вашего кода получить комбинацию `0,1,0`  - число 2 с размером `3`? Или ваш код просто проверяет биты в числе, работая как битовая маска?

Comment: И у вас будут проблемы с комбинациями из 32+ знаков. int больше битов не вместит и код упадет с кАкой типа **"память не может быть read"**

Comment: @MiKeBu Комбинацию получать вообще нигде не требуется. Автор просил двумерный массив `bool`. Вот мой класс как раз и ведет себя как такой массив. Например, получить нужный бит числа `2` размера `3` можно так: `t[2, 0]` - старший бит, `t[2, 2]` - младший бит. // Да, я знаю про ограничение количества битов. Для этого случая будет разумно заменить `int` на `ulong`. Но цель данного поста - проиллюстрировать подход, а не выкатить коммерческий код с коментами, проверками и блэкджеком.

Comment: @MiKeBu Более того, при большом количестве битов это как раз наиболее оправданный подход, поскольку реально размещать в памяти двумерный массив битов всех 64-битных чисел - это, по-моему, не совсем разумно.

Answer (score 1):

Для языка PHP:

`$arr = range(0, 1<<$k-1);`